# Which places in Düsseldorf are there where I can take courses to learn German?

Tags: learning

Currently I am in Düsseldorf and I want to take this chance to learn German. I will stay for about 2 months. which places can I take courses at reasonable prices?

Also if there is proven courses, I can take self-study courses as well.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.duesseldorf.de/vhs/programm/semester/4031000005.shtml

Answer (score 2):

The Goethe institute in Düsseldorf was excellent. I went there for a whole summer.

http://www.goethe.de/ins/de/ort/due/enindex.htm